# How to use Open Graph on non-html pages

Tags: go, facebook-opengraph

I'm building an app where users can share download links to files. These files are served using `golang`'s `http.ServeContent`, so they are sent as is, without any HTML. However, when these files are shared on social media platforms or a messaging service, I want to be able to display an image à-la Open Graph.

Is it possible to have Open Graph metadata tags show up for these non-HTML pages?

If it's not, is there any way to embed this content in an HTML5 page while still triggering a download of the file (and not the HTML page) when used with something like, e.g., `curl`?

Follow up question if none of these are possible, is there anything else I could use to have an image and a title show up when my link is shared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest not linking the direct file, but having an actual download page for them, so that the file is not linked directly, but its download page.

On the download page you could then implement the appropriate share buttons and initiate the download through a bit of JavaScript.

Alternatively you could inspect if a bot (like facebook, telegram, skype, etc) is visiting the files location and then display the appropriate open graph or twitter headers.

Example of a user agent parser: https://github.com/mssola/user_agent

Comment: I need the file to be a direct download to avoid breaking other parts of the app where it will just open the file as a video/music/image file accordingly. I'll try giving a go at the user-agent solution.